React native and sqlite DB: error code 1: no such table (while it exsists)
I'm trying to get a sqlite DB working in my react native (with expo) app, but I'm having troubles. I've created the DB command line in my assets/DB folder and created a table with 1 entry. I can query the DB in my IDE and I do find my entry so the table exists.
But when I launch my app, I get the error that no table was found. I had it working once, but while I didnt change the code.. it doesn't work now.
App.tsx
const configDatabase = async () => {
    const dbName = 'watchmeDB.db';
    const dbAsset = require('./assets/DB/watchmeDB.db');
    const dbUri = Asset.fromModule(dbAsset).uri;
    const dbFilePath = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/${dbName}`;

    try {
        FileSystem.getInfoAsync(`${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/watchmeDB.db`)
            .then(result => {
                if (result.exists) {
                    const db = SQLite.openDatabaseAsync('watchmeDB.db');
                } else {
                    FileSystem.downloadAsync(
                        Asset.fromModule(require('./assets/DB/watchmeDB.db')).uri,
                        `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/watchmeDB.db`
                    ).then(() => {
                        const db = SQLite.openDatabaseAsync('watchmeDB.db');
                    });
                }
            });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

...


useEffect(() => {
            configDatabase()
            .then(() => {
                setDbLoaded(true);
            })
            .catch((error) => console.error(error));
        }
    ,[])

...

return <SafeAreaProvider
            initialMetrics={initialWindowMetrics}
            onLayout={onLayoutRootView}
        >
            <StatusBar style="dark"/>
            <Suspense fallback={fallback}>
                <SQLite.SQLiteProvider assetSource={{ assetId: require('./assets/DB/watchmeDB.db') }}  databaseName="watchmeDB.db" useSuspense>
                    <NavigationContainer theme={globalTheme}>
                        ...
                    </NavigationContainer>
                </SQLite.SQLiteProvider>
            </Suspense>
        </SafeAreaProvider>






HomeScreen.tsx
const db = useSQLiteContext();

    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
        // db.withTransactionAsync(async () => {
        //     await getData();
        // })
    }, [db]);

    async function getData() {
        const result = await db.getAllAsync<Item>(`select * from watchme`);
        console.log(result);
        // setItems(result);
    }

Do I also need to add something to make it read/write? So I can also use insert queries.

Have you tried setting your dbFilePath to something like ${FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'SQLite/watchmeDB.db'}

Yup, but no result :(

Here what you are missing is, creating a DB. you must create a new DB in all cases even if you are accessing an already created DB you need to initialize it like bellow:
useEffect(() => {
        const ConntectToSql = async () => {
            try {
                const db = await SQLite.openDatabase({ name: 'watchmeDB', createFromLocation: '~www/watchmeDB.db' });
                console.log(db)
            } catch (error) {
                alert(error.message)
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
        ConntectToSql()
    }, []);


On my SQLite I can only choose between openDatabaseAsync or openDatabaseSync which doesn't support the above parameters. Would I need to place it behind the configDatabase function in the effect or everywhere where I can some DB functions?
